# Lock transfer of erc721 NFT

Tags: solidity, nft

Hi all I am building a blockchain-based game around an NFT project and am looking to understand if it's possible to implement the following.

Have a method on the NFT contract that when called can locks the transfer of all minted NFT's for a period. A bit like a game of tag than when your tag the contract all the (NFT / players) cant (move /transfer)

I assume I would need overide the transfer method then do a boolean check.
Something like

```
    function safeTransferFrom(
            address from,
            address to,
            uint256 tokenId
        ) public virtual override {
            if(!isLocked){
            safeTransferFrom(from, to, tokenId, "");
}
        }
```

Will this work as I expect and is there any issues with this and would override the transfer method especially around security etc.

Sorry for such a broad question

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

From the context, it seems like you're using the OpenZeppelin [implementation](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol). If that's the case, you can override their `_beforeTokenTransfer()` function, which is effectively called from **all** functions performing token transfer (as there is multiple of them).

```
pragma solidity ^0.8;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";

contract MyCollection is ERC721 {
    constructor() ERC721("MyCollection", "MyC") {
        _mint(msg.sender, 1);
    }

    // needs to be unlocked for the `_mint()` function in constructor
    bool locked = false;

    function setLocked(bool _locked) external {
        locked = _locked;
    }

    function _beforeTokenTransfer(
        address from,
        address to,
        uint256 tokenId
    ) internal override {
        require(!locked, "Cannot transfer - currently locked");
    }
}
```

If you're using other or custom implementation, or chose to only override the publicly visible functions, make sure that there is no other `public` or `external` function allowing the transfer without the lock mechanism.

---

Also few notes to your current code:

- You probably won't need the `virtual` keyword. It allows the function to be further overridden. Unless you're expecting to override this function as well, you can safely remove the keyword.
- You're calling the parent function with the same name but different argument set. If you wanted to call the parent function with the same name **and** the same argument set (assuming it's defined), you'd need to use the `super` keyword (same as in Java): `super.safeTransferFrom(from, to, tokenId);`

Comment: Do this only after sold out because you won't be able to mint anymore.